# Match 2 fields in different records Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Goodmorning

I am trying to match certain fields over a dataset. The dataset contains records like:

```
{
    "token" : "17e0d95f2e2112443cfb09970ae9140e",
    "answers" : {
        "Yourname" : "Marco",
        "youremail" : "marco@me.nl",
        "recemail" : "sonja@me.nl"
    }
},


{
    "token" : "cf5ae65b05249dc6b2a0c99c4cf9688e",
    "answers" : {
        "yourname" : "Sonja",
        "youremail" : "sonja@me.nl",
        "recemail" : "marco@me.nl"
    }
}
```

In this case, it should match the two because the `recemail` (recipients email) matches someone else's email address. And vice versa. 
What I am trying to find is how to find these two records (in a larger dataset with more of these matches).

So, Marco's `recemail` should find Sonja's `youremail` and these two matches should then be made available to save into another collection, but that's not the important part here.

hope someone can help me with this query
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need `X.youremail == Y.recemail && X.recemail == Y.youremail`? Or just `X.youremail == Y.recemail || X.recemail == Y.youremail`?

Comment: Like this. ```X.recemail == Y.youremail && Y.recemail == X.youremail```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will return an array of 2-entry arrays. Each 2-entry array is made of the sender email and the recipient email. Each pair will appear only once. In other words, you'll get `["marco@me.nl", "sonja@me.nl"]` but not `["sonja@me.nl", "marco@me.nl"]`.

```js
var list = [{
    "token" : "17e0d95f2e2112443cfb09970ae9140e",
    "answers" : {
        "Yourname" : "Marco",
        "youremail": "marco@me.nl",
        "recemail" : "sonja@me.nl" }
  }, {
    "token" : "cf5ae65b05249dc6b2a0c99c4cf9688e",
    "answers" : {
        "yourname" : "Sonja",
        "youremail": "sonja@me.nl",
        "recemail" : "marco@me.nl" }
  }, {
    "token" : "fe2c2740e083dfe02cc7e96520a0e079",
    "answers" : {
        "yourname" : "Joe",
        "youremail": "joe@foo.com",
        "recemail" : "mike@bar.com" }
  }
];

var res = [], sz = list.length;

list.forEach(function(obj, pos) {
  for(var i = pos + 1; i < sz; i++) {
    if(
      list[i].answers.youremail == obj.answers.recemail &&
      list[i].answers.recemail == obj.answers.youremail
    ) {
      res.push([ obj.answers.youremail, obj.answers.recemail ]);
    }
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but the question has to do with the Mongoose query. This works, and I can fetch all and then on node get to the data I want, but it is the MongoDB query that I originally need. If I don't get a satisfying answer I will definitely go with your answer tho. :)

Comment: @Marco Ah well. Thanks for having accepted this and sorry for not being able to help your more on that one.